# change charset and collation of mysql database

Tags: asp.net, mysql, character, collation

How to configure MySQL database and asp.net project so that default character set was utf8 and collation was utf8_general_ci?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the mysql databse as shown below or see more for other settings on this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

From ASP.NET you can set charset to UTF8 by the connectionstring

this way

```
"Server=DB_SERVER_NAME;Database=DBNAME;Uid=YOUR_ID;Pwd=YOUR_PASSWORD;Charset=utf8;"
```

Comment: I didn't specify Charset=utf8; in the connection string. Very nice, thanks!